# Replicating a long form entry table design considerations

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I am currently converting a paper based system over to a new web portal. When the company (a medical practice) enrolls a new patient, there is a particular form that the patient currently fills out. This form contains 28 questions with as many as 20 different yes/no options per question.

My question is, should I create one table with many columns (possibly as many as 300, mostly containing BIT fields) or should I normalize it in some way?

All of the fields are associated with a single entity; the reason a patient is here.

In my experience of database design, huge tables with 100+ columns are generally frowned upon however I'd like to see what the community thinks of this example.

Comment: Do you need to search on answers (i.e. "give me patients who answered given question in a given way")?

Comment: Are there several versions of the form, either for different types of patients or alterations over time?  Any expectation that you will need to manage form revisions in the future?  (My doctor's office used a form for years that inquired about "Martial _[sic]_ Status: Single, Married, Divorced, Widow(er)" until I pointed out that some people are happily married.)

Answer (score 2):

When using many boolean (`BIT`) fields, sometimes it's better to use a single `INT` field which is a bitwise sum. This simplifies the storage and table definition, but makes the code more complicated. Say you have a table Patients and some numeric values with different meanings: is on medication, is allergic on paracetamol, is diabetic etc. When you insert the ticked fields, you simply sum the corresponding numeric values. When performing select statements, you will do bit a bitwise-and comparison: `TotalValue & Value = Value`. 
Here is a bit of code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Patients(Id INT, PatientName VARCHAR(50), MiscIssues INT)

DECLARE @IsOnMedication TINYINT = 2
DECLARE @IsParacetamolAllergic TINYINT = 4
DECLARE @IsDiabetic TINYINT = 8

INSERT INTO #Patients
VALUES
    (1, 'A', @IsDiabetic + @IsOnMedication)
    , (2, 'B', @IsDiabetic + @IsOnMedication + @IsParacetamolAllergic)

SELECT * FROM #Patients WHERE MiscIssues & @IsDiabetic = @IsDiabetic

DROP TABLE #Patients
```

Another option is to use custom fields, but in my experience this approach performs poorly when you have a large amount of records.

Comment: That's an interesting way to go about it. I think that a "form builder" is inevitable at some point but as this is a proof of concept I've been given the go ahead to build the data as static so your concept of a bitwise operation is something I like.